# My Matomo installation doesn't work on desktop

Tags: matomo

Matomo doesn't work on desktop release.

> Ooops ... there was a problem during the request. Maybe the server had
>   a temporary problem or maybe you requested a report with too much
>   data.

This is the matomo.log:
'''
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] Uncaught exception: /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/templates/_visitorLogIcons.twig(16): The string to escape is not a valid UTF-8 string.
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] The string to escape is not a valid UTF-8 string.
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #0 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/Twig.php(69): twig_escape_filter(Object(Twig\Environment), 'San Mart\xEDn de l...', 'html_attr', 'UTF-8', false)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #1 /membri/impressionism/matomo/tmp/templates_c/8f/8f3293af9e355d51978f0a1005aca83f01464bfbc8d55751a8d3178f9975d9bf.php(64): Piwik\piwik_escape_filter(Object(Twig\Environment), 'San Mart\xEDn de l...', 'html_attr')
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #2 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(455): __TwigTemplate_48ad10421548dbe27c8ef303b7c040c271a9b7e5cb17d293981650bfb3aee5ce->doDisplay(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #3 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(422): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #4 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(434): Twig\Template->display(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #5 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(47): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #6 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(384): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #7 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(311): Twig\Environment->render('@Live/_visitorL...', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #8 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(295): Piwik\View->renderTwigTemplate()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #9 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/VisitorDetails.php(126): Piwik\View->render()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #10 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Live.php(138): Piwik\Plugins\Live\VisitorDetails->renderIcons(Object(Piwik\DataTable\Row))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #11 [internal function]: Piwik\Plugins\Live\Live->renderVisitorIcons('', Object(Piwik\DataTable\Row))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #12 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/EventDispatcher.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #13 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/Piwik.php(775): Piwik\EventDispatcher->postEvent('Live.renderVisi...', Array, false, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #14 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/Twig.php(289): Piwik\Piwik::postEvent('Live.renderVisi...', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #15 /membri/impressionism/matomo/tmp/templates_c/47/4700797b9f5741a2216205f8c2053127fd14c140de58d5313fc3939e2f7b25b9.php(123): Piwik\Twig->Piwik{closure}('Live.renderVisi...', Object(Piwik\DataTable\Row))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #16 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(455): __TwigTemplate_f7387213c57911a4fe2fa844a9dea404f3cc42ae869b2de1f203141fa4f2e5f3->doDisplay(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #17 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(422): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #18 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(434): Twig\Template->display(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #19 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(47): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #20 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(384): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #21 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(311): Twig\Environment->render('@Live/getLastVi...', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #22 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(295): Piwik\View->renderTwigTemplate()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #23 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Controller.php(58): Piwik\View->render()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #24 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Controller.php(101): Piwik\Plugins\Live\Controller->render(Object(Piwik\View))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #25 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Controller.php(41): Piwik\Plugins\Live\Controller->getLastVisitsStart()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #26 [internal function]: Piwik\Plugins\Live\Controller->widget()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #27 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/FrontController.php(590): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #28 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/FrontController.php(165): Piwik\FrontController->doDispatch('Live', 'widget', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #29 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/dispatch.php(34): Piwik\FrontController->dispatch()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #30 /membri/impressionism/matomo/index.php(27): require_once('/membri/impress...')
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:25:07 UTC] [b5304] #31 {main}
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] Uncaught exception: /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/templates/_visitorLogIcons.twig(16): The string to escape is not a valid UTF-8 string.
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] The string to escape is not a valid UTF-8 string.
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #0 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/Twig.php(69): twig_escape_filter(Object(Twig\Environment), 'San Mart\xEDn de l...', 'html_attr', 'UTF-8', false)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #1 /membri/impressionism/matomo/tmp/templates_c/8f/8f3293af9e355d51978f0a1005aca83f01464bfbc8d55751a8d3178f9975d9bf.php(64): Piwik\piwik_escape_filter(Object(Twig\Environment), 'San Mart\xEDn de l...', 'html_attr')
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #2 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(455): __TwigTemplate_48ad10421548dbe27c8ef303b7c040c271a9b7e5cb17d293981650bfb3aee5ce->doDisplay(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #3 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(422): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #4 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(434): Twig\Template->display(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #5 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(47): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #6 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(384): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #7 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(311): Twig\Environment->render('@Live/_visitorL...', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #8 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(295): Piwik\View->renderTwigTemplate()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #9 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/VisitorDetails.php(126): Piwik\View->render()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #10 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Live.php(138): Piwik\Plugins\Live\VisitorDetails->renderIcons(Object(Piwik\DataTable\Row))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #11 [internal function]: Piwik\Plugins\Live\Live->renderVisitorIcons('', Object(Piwik\DataTable\Row))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #12 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/EventDispatcher.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #13 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/Piwik.php(775): Piwik\EventDispatcher->postEvent('Live.renderVisi...', Array, false, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #14 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/Twig.php(289): Piwik\Piwik::postEvent('Live.renderVisi...', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #15 /membri/impressionism/matomo/tmp/templates_c/47/4700797b9f5741a2216205f8c2053127fd14c140de58d5313fc3939e2f7b25b9.php(123): Piwik\Twig->Piwik{closure}('Live.renderVisi...', Object(Piwik\DataTable\Row))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #16 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(455): __TwigTemplate_f7387213c57911a4fe2fa844a9dea404f3cc42ae869b2de1f203141fa4f2e5f3->doDisplay(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #17 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(422): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #18 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(434): Twig\Template->display(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #19 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(47): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #20 /membri/impressionism/matomo/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(384): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #21 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(311): Twig\Environment->render('@Live/getLastVi...', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #22 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/View.php(295): Piwik\View->renderTwigTemplate()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #23 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Controller.php(58): Piwik\View->render()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #24 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Controller.php(101): Piwik\Plugins\Live\Controller->render(Object(Piwik\View))
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #25 /membri/impressionism/matomo/plugins/Live/Controller.php(41): Piwik\Plugins\Live\Controller->getLastVisitsStart()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #26 [internal function]: Piwik\Plugins\Live\Controller->widget()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #27 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/FrontController.php(590): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #28 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/FrontController.php(165): Piwik\FrontController->doDispatch('Live', 'widget', Array)
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #29 /membri/impressionism/matomo/core/dispatch.php(34): Piwik\FrontController->dispatch()
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #30 /membri/impressionism/matomo/index.php(27): require_once('/membri/impress...')
ERROR Piwik\FrontController[2020-05-31 18:29:50 UTC] [c2ce5] #31 {main}
'''
Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue `The string to escape is not a valid UTF-8 string` is fixed in Matomo 4 currently in development. If you are blocked, you can always try to upgrade to the Matomo 4 in development at: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo (branch `4.x-dev`). Learn more about the issue here: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/14485
which was fixed in https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/pull/15618
(will be released in Matomo 4 in a few months)